Angular how to swap two components inside dynamic container
I have a dynamic container that shows 2 components at a time using a paginator. I want to be able to swap a component with its previous/next and so far it's working; however, when I try to swap the first element of a page with its previous element it doesn't get rerendered (but gets swapped correctly, when I go to the previous page I can see the element swapped).
StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rgvd2n

There seems to be a bug related to previousPageIndex, the function handlePaginator if condition, is not allowing the function to execute and hence you are not seeing the view updated.
handlePaginator(event: PageEvent): void {
  // if (event.pageIndex === event.previousPageIndex) {
  //   return;
  // }

  this.paginationData.pageIndex = event.pageIndex;

  const start = event.pageIndex * event.pageSize;
  const end = (event.pageIndex + 1) * event.pageSize;

  for (const [index, element] of this.elementsRefs.entries()) {
    element.location.nativeElement.style.display =
      index >= start && index < end ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
}

On reorder, we need to trigger the handlePaginator which updates the view display property.
reference.instance.swap.subscribe((indexDelta) => {
  const index = this.elementsRefs.indexOf(reference);
  const swapWith = index + indexDelta;

  if (swapWith < 0 || swapWith >= this.elementsRefs.length) {
    return;
  }

  [this.elementsRefs[index], this.elementsRefs[swapWith]] = [
    this.elementsRefs[swapWith],
    this.elementsRefs[index],
  ];
  this.sectionContainerRef.move(reference.hostView, swapWith);
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

  this.handlePaginator({
    length: this.paginationData.length,
    pageIndex: this.paginationData.pageIndex,
    pageSize: this.paginationData.pageSize,
    previousPageIndex: undefined,
  });
});


Stackblitz Demo
